# Missing MySQL in PHPinfo on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I am working on a newly built Ubuntu server with Apache2, MySQL 5 and PHP 5.3.2 . It seems something is incomplete in the configuration.  When I call phpinfo() there is no MySQL section in it. However, the "Additional .ini files parsed" section shows "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini "

In my research I have seen references to uncommenting an extension line in the PHP .ini file, but I don't see any line like that in my .ini.

I have been using MySQL from a remote GUI for a week with no problems, so I know the database install is fine.  PHP runs completely normal except for not talking to MySQL.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.
Paul

Answer (score 8):

Fixed it by running  `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` . Found this solution at http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-10.04-lamp-p2